# regEx insert symbols into number string python

Tags: python, regex, string, timestamp, numbers

I am trying to convert a number string into something that I convert into time/date later on.

I start with a list of folder names:

```
event_name_list = ['noEvent_20161208174900', 'NoEvent_20161209174200', 'NoEvent20161211061400']
```

And get just the numbers from these using:

```
event_time = re.findall(r'\d+', event)
print event_time 
['20161208174900']
```

I want to convert `event_time` into `20161208 17:49:00` so that it can be converted to a time using `pd.to_datetime`. I have tried the code below but I get the below shown errors and not able to move forward.

```
event_time = re.sub(r '(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)','\1-\2:\3:\4' event_time)
invalid syntax

event_time = re.sub(event_time, '(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)', '\1-\2:\3:\4')
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

event_time = re.sub(r'(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)', '\1-\2:\3:\4', event_time)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: FYI: `'\1-\2:\3:\4'` is not what you think. Use `r'\1-\2:\3:\4'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks. I stil get `invalid syntax` errors with `event_time = re.sub(r'(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)', r'\1-\2:\3:\4' event_time)` though.

Comment: You missed a comma before `event_time` (but make sure you use a *string* `event_time` variable, not a list)